# symfony2 routing issue

Tags: symfony, routes

Okay, so I have an entity with crud created right...  and it gives me the .yml routing file for the entity...

in the yml file I have specified a route such as:

```
manager_agentview:
    pattern: /manager/{id}/view
    defaults: { _controller: "EcsCrmBundle:Management:agentview" }
```

This works perfectly...  However, the contents of this page is a list...

My function, is like this:

```
public function agentviewAction($id, $start = null, $end = null) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $request = $this->getRequest();
            $today = time();
            echo $end;
            if ($end == null) {
                if (date('l') == "Saturday") { $end = date("Y-m-d 23:59:59"); } else { $end = date("Y-m-d 23:59:59", strtotime('next saturday', $today)); }
            }
            if ($start == null) {
                if (date('l') == "Sunday") { $start = date('Y-m-d 00:00:00'); } else { $start = date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', strtotime('last sunday', $today)); }
            }
            $entities = $em->getRepository('EcsCrmBundle:TimeClock');
            $query = $entities->createQueryBuilder('t');
            $query = $query->select('t')
                  ->where('t.daydate BETWEEN :start AND :end')
                  ->andwhere("t.noteBy = :id")
                  ->orderBy("t.id", 'ASC')
                  ->setParameter('start', $start)
                  ->setParameter('end', $end)
                  ->setParameter('id', $id)
                  ->getQuery();
            $entities = $query->getArrayResult();
            $dateRangeForm = $this->createForm(new DateRangeType());

            $query = $em->getRepository('EcsAgentManagerBundle:User')->find($id);

            //return new Response('yep', 200);
            return $this->render('EcsCrmBundle:TimeClock:view.html.twig', array('entity' =>$entities, 'user' => $query, 'start' => $start, 'end' => $end, 'form' => $dateRangeForm -> createView(),));  
    }
```

the dateRangeForm, simply creates 2 jquery datepicker boxes..

But, when I add in `{start}/{end}` to my route, it constantly tells me that it can't find the proper route....  Since I want the URL to stay the same (ultimately - without the dates being in the URL) -- I've got to figure out how to post the data to the same function without breaking the ability to just view it by just going to something like:  site.dev/manager/12/view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to be able to have a single controller function that handles

/manager/1/view/start_date/end_date

and also handles

/manager/1/view

Correct?

There are two solutions to this. The first is to create an optional placeholder, which is described here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html. Basically, you can update your route to look like this:

```
manager_agentview:
pattern: /manager/{id}/view/{start}/{end}
defaults: { _controller: "EcsCrmBundle:Management:agentview", start: null, end: null}
```

The route will then still match /manager/1/view and will set start and end to NULL.

The second solution would be to create multiple routes that all point to the same controller, one version with the start and end dates and one version without them. The only reason I can think of that you might want to do this would be if you didn't want your route to match a URL that contained a start but no end, since the above solution would still match in that case.